# How to show a set of vectors do not span a space without computation?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, euclidean-geometry

Let

$U_1 = (1, 1, 0, 0)$

$U_2 = (1, 0, 1, 0)$

$U_3 = (0, 0, 1, 1)$

Without doing any computation, explain why span$\{U_1, U_2, U_3\}$ $\neq$ $\mathbb{R}^4$.

I could reduce it to reduced row echelon form via Gaussian Elimination but that will not satisfy the condition of 'without doing any computation'. Is there any way I can do this problem without computation?

Comment: Do you know dimension?

Comment: Yes I do know dimensions. However, I believe I should show some proof, which I don't know how to without computation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The space $\mathbb R^4$ has dimension four.

Answer (score 1):

3 vectors can span 3 dimensions at most.

Answer (score 0):

An argument based on dimension is the simplest way to go. If you don’t like that approach, here’s another, although it may not qualify as “without computation.”

Consider the vector $(0,0,0,1)$. What linear combination of the given vectors can produce it? There must be a non-zero multiple of $U_3$ since that’s the only one with a non-zero fourth coordinate. This means that you also have to have a non-zero multiple of $U_2$ to cancel the third coordinate that $U_3$ brings with it, which in turn requires a non-zero multiple of $U_1$ to cancel the first coordinate that came with $U_2$, but now you’re stuck with no way to cancel the non-zero second coordinate of $U_1$ since it’s zero in the other two vectors. So, you have an element of $\mathbb R^4$ that’s not in the span of the three given vectors.